# How to implement OAuth for a "personal feed dashboard" application?

Tags: api, web-applications, oauth, architecture, oauth-2.0

I am building a web application to display all my activity from selected sources around the web in a single page. So far I have been successful at either using well document and easy to consume APIs (vimeo being one such example) or manually requesting and parsing feeds for other sources (eg: medium).

However, there is also the case where there is no sufficient feed provided and the API requires some sort of authentication before I can query for any kind of data. And here is when I face an "architectural" problem:

I want the application to be accessible by other people but if the authentication part is required for the API usage, how is it supposed to be performed? Also, what do I do if in the future I decide to have other people signup and get their activities displayed in their pages as well?

A very solid example is youtube: I want you to visit my page and see my "liked" videos (sorted by date), but their API requires me to be authenticated so it can query for my liked videos playlist..

So, yeah, any sort of help -even in the form of direction leads- would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how people can trust your service with login and password if the other service doesn't provide OAuth. Entering login and password every time also doesn't help, because different services will have different logins and passwords.

Comment: @TimothyHa Let's take other people off the todo list for now then, how do I make this work even just for me? Do I have to login at all these services everytime I visit the page?

Comment: If I would do authentication and content grabbing for myself, maybe some cURL sessions with cookies enabled would help. And password for authentication could be stored securely in your database with some "master password" encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Most cloud services support OAuth. You need to register your application with the cloud service, like YouTube, and let your users allow access to your application at YouTube.

You can check out http://yoke.io, a personal dashboard app we are working on, to see how this works. There are more popular cloud "aggregators" like HootSuite and Slack.